# page() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number' in django

Tags: django, pagination

So, I am trying to add pagination to my django website. Here is the code for my view function that handles pagination:

```
def index(request):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    latest_post = object_list.last()
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = Paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'blog/index.html',{
        'posts':posts,
        'latest_post':latest_post,
        'page':page,
        })
```

I am getting an error on line 11, inside the `try` block. Where is the error?

Comment: int(page)... try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.GET.get('page')` returns `None` and thus it fails in the next line because page number is required. It's better to use [Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view-function) this way:

```
paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3)
page = request.GET.get('page')
posts = paginator.get_page(page)
```

`get_page()` method handles this case and it will return page 1 in case it's `None`. [Here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/paginator.py#L67) is the line in the source code where this happens.